# Waves animation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, settimeout, setinterval

I want to show waves animation of loud speaker. There are 3 waves coming from a loudspeaker. I want to show like this :-

```
1st wave will be shown in 1 sec, 
2nd wave will be shown in 2 sec,
3rd wave will be shown in 3 sec,


and then all waves will be disappear and it will start again.
```

[image]

I have tried following code :-

```
$('.waves1').hide();
$('.waves2').hide();
$('.waves3').hide();
$('.waves4').hide();


function waveIt(element, times, klass, delay) 
{
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(element).show();
                }, delay + (300 * i));


            };


        };

        waveIt('.waves1', 10, 'i_waveflash1', 1000);
        waveIt('.waves2', 10, 'i_waveflash2', 2000);
        waveIt('.waves3', 10, 'i_waveflash3', 3000);
```

**It initially shows 1 by 1 after a 1 sec interval but after completing it does not start again**.I want to start it again. Sorry for my bad English and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial impression is that you should probably use an animated GIF to do this.  However, I'm not exactly sure about your use case so I will provide the javascript that can do this for you.  Basically, you have to use setTimeout in a recursive way.

Here's the JS Fiddle that show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/H8R5b/

**Javascript**

```
var showNextWave = function() {
    var hiddenWaveEls = $('.waves:not(.active)');
    if (hiddenWaveEls.length > 0) {
        hiddenWaveEls.first().show().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.waves').hide().removeClass('active');
    }
    setTimeout(showNextWave, 1000);
};

setTimeout(showNextWave, 1000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="waves1" class="waves">1</div>
<div id="waves2" class="waves">2</div>
<div id="waves3" class="waves">3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.waves {
    display: none;
}
```

**Explanation**

I have created a function showNextWave that will check the state of the wave and find the next wave that needs to be displayed.  State is managed using the class name active on each wave.  If all waves are visible, then I hide them all and remove the active class name.

The showNextWave function is also designed to be recursive so that it executes every 1 second using the setTimeout function.

Comment: You can also use setInterval instead of using a recursive solution involving setTimeout.  JS Fiddle with setInterval: http://jsfiddle.net/QyAgj/